# How can I change the .dll search path my application uses?

Tags: c++, dll, mingw-w64

As my application grows, I find myself using more and more third-party libraries, and the number of .dll's in my application directory is growing (11 at the time of this writing).  This isn't really a *problem*, per se, but it is ugly.  I would much rather be able to put these in "`bin/`" or something.

Can this be done, or am I wasting my time on something that's not really an issue?

The only *real* advantage this would give me would that I could put the x86 and x64 versions of the exe in the same directory, and have them load from the appropriate folder of dll's (`bin32/` or `bin64/`, for instance).

I'm using C++ and MinGW-W64.

Answer (score 1):

The following link explains the DLL Search order very nicely.
Quoting:

> Before the system searches for a DLL, it checks the following:
>   If a DLL with the same module name is already loaded in memory, the system uses the loaded DLL, no matter which directory it is in. The system does not search for the DLL.
>   If the DLL is on the list of known DLLs for the version of Windows on which the application is running, the system uses its copy of the known DLL (and the known DLL's dependent DLLs, if any). The system does not search for the DLL.
>   For a list of known DLLs on the current system, see the following registry key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\KnownDLLs.

You can refer to using SetDllDirectory to add custom search directories.

[Dynamic-Link Library Search Order on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted, it looks like it contains a correct answer: call `SetDllDirectory` (although it seems the documentation for `SetDllDirectory` should be read closely).

Comment: Link only answers are strongly discouraged on SO.

Comment: Sorry, added some explanation

Answer (score 1):

You can use the GNU linker's `-rpath` flag.

For example, this will search the local directory for dependent dlls: `-Wl,-rpath,./`

So specifically in your case you'd want: `-Wl,-rpath,./bin`

Comment: This works for me when I run the program within code::blocks, but not when I run a release build elsewhere.

Comment: "elsewhere" ? what compiler or linker are you using over there ? This is a GNU linker flag. And of course you'd have to set it in any Makefile or build configuration you use.

Comment: What I mean is, when I'm working within code::blocks and I hit the "run" or "build and run" button, it works fine, pulling the dll's from `bin/` as desired.  When I create a release build, and copy the executable to, say, a folder on my desktop, it complains about missing .dll's unless I put them in the same directory as the executable.

Comment: Did you check with dependency walker (or ldd if you're on linux) if all the files it's looking for are there and in the right directories? And did you set any environment variables inside the IDE project?

Comment: I spoke too soon, now `-Wl,-rpath,./bin` isn't doing anything at all, even within code::blocks.

Comment: You are doing it for each output dll separately right? I mean the main executable would have to search under ./bin, but the dlls themselves should each look in their local directory.

Comment: I'm not outputting dll's, I'm outputting an exe that links to dll's at runtime.